# React-Redux User State is not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a state that is getting the right object from my action but It won't seem to actually append to the state.  Does anyone have any experience working with reducers in React-Redux that can lend a hand? I'm not sure why I can't return the new state.

Here is the code in progress I have at the moment.

```
import * as types from '../constants'
const defaultState = {}
const userReducer = (state = defaultState, action) =>{
    switch(action.type){
        case types.USER_LOGGED_IN:
            console.log("in the logged in reducer")
            console.log(action.cookie)
            return {
                ...state, 
                cookie: action.cookie
            }
        case types.USER_LOGGED_OUT:
            return state
        default:
            return state        
    }

}

export default userReducer
```

The console.log will actually print out the correct cookie value for me.  Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated.

per Request here is the container,

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import { routerActions } from 'react-router-redux'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import GoogleLogin from '../components/GoogleLogin'
import actions from '../actions/'
import cookie from 'react-cookie'
const login = actions.userActions.login

function select(state, ownProps) {
  const isAuthenticated = state.user.cookie || false
  console.log(isAuthenticated)
  const redirect = ownProps.location.query.redirect || '/'
  return {
    isAuthenticated,
    redirect
  }
}

class LoginContainer extends Component {



    componentWillMount() {
      const { isAuthenticated, replace, redirect } = this.props      
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        replace(redirect)
      }

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      const { isAuthenticated, replace, redirect } = nextProps
      const { isAuthenticated: wasAuthenticated } = this.props

      if (!wasAuthenticated && isAuthenticated) {
        replace(redirect)
      }
    }

    onClick(e){
      e.preventDefault()
      //console.log("in the onClick")
      var status = cookie.load("MarketingStatsApp",false) 
      if(!(status == undefined)){
        const login = actions.userActions.login
        this.props.login({
        cookie: status

        })
      }

      window.location.href='auth/google'

    };

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Login using Google</h1>
          <GoogleLogin onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
      )
    }

}

export default connect(select, { login, replace: routerActions.replace })(LoginContainer)
```

Here you can see the false get printed out the first time through and then the cookie get printed out.  You can even see the action but I can't click into the arrows for that action and the the other ones don't display the updated state as how I expect it to be

[image]

Comment: This looks right to me. How are you observing the problem? I suspect the issue is where you are using the state, not in the reducer.

Comment: yes your reducer is ok, please provide the code of your container

Comment: Thanks for the help, I added the container to the post

Comment: can you show your whole console with all the logs ? Also can you log your `state` under `select` method. ?

Comment: Thanks panther here is the update

Comment: Your question is really vague... What result do you expect to see? A change in state after `onClick` is called? Also no where in the code I see `dispatch` is used.

Comment: Dispatch is pulled into this.props from connect so by calling this.props.login it is dispatching it.  My expectation is in the reducer it should return a new and updated state instead of the same one, as I can see the cookie log to the console correctly in the reducer right above the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone

The problem ended up being on my double verification on my router page.  I needed to re-bring in the action variable for it to launch properly. Here is the code for that

```
import { Router, Route, browserHistory,IndexRedirect } from 'react-router'
import React from 'react';
import Layout from './components/Layout'
import Home from './containers/Home'
import Login from './containers/LoginContainer'
import Dashboard from './containers/Dashboard'

import { UserIsAuthenticated} from './util/wrapper'
import cookie from 'react-cookie'
import axios from 'axios'
import actions from './actions'
import store from './reducers';
const Authenticated = UserIsAuthenticated((props) => props.children)


function doubleCheckGUID(guid){

  return axios.post("/auth/guid",{guid: guid}).then(response => {

   const login = actions.userActions.login
   store.dispatch(login({
           cookie: cookie.load("MarketingStatsApp",false)
        }))

    return true;
  }).catch(error => {
    return false;
  })

}
if(cookie.load("MarketingStatsApp",false)){
    doubleCheckGUID(cookie.load("MarketingStatsApp",false))
}


const AppRouter = () =>
  <Router history={browserHistory} >
    <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
        <IndexRedirect to="/home" />
        <Route path="home" component={Home} />
        <Route path="login" component={Login}/>
        <Route component={Authenticated} >
            <Route path="dash" component={Dashboard} /> 
        </Route>
    </Route>
  </Router>

export default AppRouter
```